# Can't install BeautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have dificulties using Python. When installing in PyCharm, I obtain the error message below:

[image]

I do not know why this happens. I am able to install it in the terminal with `pip install --user BeautifulSoup` but not in PyCharm.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install the obsolete BeautifulSoup 3 (which only supports Python 2) under Python 3, hence the error.  You should instead install [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) (all one word) which supports both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could show me how.

Comment: I've installed soup4 through the Terminal as well, but f'ing Python doesnt pick it up

Comment: @DamnPython: I've never used PyCharm, so I can't help you.  However, in order for Python 3 to recognize BeautifulSoup, you have to install it specifically for Python 3 with `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`; normal `pip` only installs for Python 2, which is effectively a separate language.

Comment: I tried that but still no avail. Is it just my computer that is f****?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hey first thing first lets breath :)

I have recently started using python quite a bit. I use it on a mac and on various linux distros.

On my mac I had a frustrating time learning how to use the correct python version and installing things, when i started out. What saved me from throwing my various things out the window was using [Anaconda Navigator](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) on my mac.

Anaconda navigator is pretty cool because it handles a lot of package installing and environments for you. For me starting with this really helped. Now after getting through the initial phase of learning the awesomeness that is python... I have gained the patience necessary to learn the different nuances that come with installing libraries and what not.

Short and sweet I took a look to see if Anaconda had install support for beatifulsoup4 and it totally does.

As if it isnt apparent from my post already... I HIGHLY RECOMMEND ANACONDA for beginning python users. That way you can focus on coding and not on package installation.

Have a good one!

Comment: Ok. It was the f***** pycharm that's a piece of trash. I've started using Wing IDE, and its much better. F*** pycharm altogether. I like Intellj's products, but this one was an absolute disappointment.